# How to check app launch once a day in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to execute some piece of code when app launch once in a day. Currently I am taking date difference and setting the **firstTime** variable value accordingly in the shared preferences But it is going quite complex.

Is there any easier approach to do so? Thanks

Comment: Sorry but what is complex in that? :-) I think that's the exact way to do

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I am thinking some kind of API available in Android OR somebody implemented in much easier way.

Comment: All you need to do is check today's date and compare to the date in preference. If it's different run the code else don't

Comment: Thanks Nabin but there is lot of use cases creating, like one when app installed first time in that case current and old date will be same.

Comment: Sorry but I can't get you. Can you elaborate what your problem really is? Mention your every possible _use cases_

Comment: Question is quite simple how to check app launch once a day in android? . you mentioned if date diff only then execute so i mentioned if i will take date diff then it will fail when date is same.

Comment: Isn't that exactly what you want?

Comment: "some kind of API available" -- no, sorry. "when app installed first time in that case current and old date will be same" -- no, the old date will be `null`, as you have not set it before.

Comment: Thank you CommonsWare I was giving old date as current date for first Time installation that's why it was going complex implementation. Such a silly mistake didn't think about it. Thanks once again

Comment: So was that all about??